# field listing in solr with "fl" parameter for a field having space in between

Tags: solr

I have a field in my solr schema as "Post Date"(exclude the quotes). when i fire a query with "fl" (field list) parameter in order to view only Post Date of search results, since this field contains a space I am not getting anything in the docs responses. I tried using +, %20 but still i get no results. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried "Post\\ Date" ?

Comment: I'm afraid you are stuck with this. Although, at the low level, neither Lucene nor Solr impose any restrictions on the field names, some things will break if you use whitespaces or other special characters in the field name. I suggest you change your schema and wipe out all those whitespaces from your field names.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to inform that i have found a solution to this. I tried experimenting and hence came up with a solution on putting `\+` as the substitute for white space in the query. Hence the query should be `Post\+Date:[ranges]`

I couldnt aford to change my schema as many teams are depending on it and we are upgrading our system to a new search engine.

Comment: sorry it got formatted..put a backslash\\ in front of the +sign

Comment: The previous post remove a //sigh which i had put. the post format for a field such as Post Date is Post//+Date

Answer (score 2):

You can specify (what Solr deems crazy) fields by wrapping them like this:

```
field(Post Date)
```

This actually changes the returned results fieldname too so you'll get back something like:

```
"field(Post Date)" : "2010-01-01"
```

And not just the name as you might imagine.

Comment: This worked for me. thanks ! Just had to use double quotes, field("Student Name") desc

Answer (score 0):

As a possible workaround, you might be able to use a wild card to achieve your results.  Using the solr wiki http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#glob you may be able to specify `fl=Post*Date` which would possibly get around your problem.  I have not verified this but it might work.

Update:  This doesn't seem to work on either version of solr I tried (1.4.0 and 3.6.1).  Looks like this may have been discussed at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldAliasesAndGlobsInParams but it does not appear to be implemented.