# Escape LukeRequest with spaces, slashes, and colon

Tags: solr, solr4, luke

I am using Solr 4.1.  Using LukeRequest, I want to get the number of documents with data for a specific field.  The name of the field is something like `http://foo.org/bar/ baz` (note the space between `bar/` and `baz`).  When I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8983/root/admin/luke` I get a list of all of my fields, including the aforementioned one.  When I visit

`http://127.0.0.1:8983/root/admin/luke?fl=http://foo.org/bar/ baz`

I get no hits.  I have tried url-encoding the string, escaping slashes, escaping the colon, escaping the space, using + instead of space, and every possible combination of backslashes I can think of.  The solution posted at another StackOverflow question [field listing in solr with "fl" parameter for a field having space in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575009/field-listing-in-solr-with-fl-parameter-for-a-field-having-space-in-between#) didn't work for me.

I am really only looking for a yes-no answer to whether any documents have a value for this particular field, so if there is a better way to do this than LukeRequest, I'm all ears for that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, escaping special characters using a backslash works for values, not for parameters like `fl` or `sort`.

This [answer on lucene mailing list](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Search-on-dynamic-fields-which-contains-spaces-special-characters-tp472100p472102.html) also confirms my thoughts. I guess you shouldn't have spaces in field names.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Removing spaces from all my field names isn't really a possibility, so I'll have to find some other workaround.

Comment: @Wiscocrew - I doubt if there's something easy that you can do, but do post back if you find a way.

Comment: I got around it by using TermsComponent.  The field name is specified as part of the query, not the parameter, so escaping works there.  The gist of what I did: `http://127.0.0.1:8983/root/terms?terms.fl=http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.org%2Fbar%2F%20baz`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could accomplish the same thing using the [TermsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) as it can tell you if there are any terms associated with a field in the index. However, you will need to specify the field name in the query, so you will run into a similar issue. As *Srikanth* answered, you are better off not using spaces or special characters in field names.