# Solr fl (field list) with space in the field name

Tags: solr

I have a solr dynamic field with a space “myfield name_solr” . Does anyone know how to use this field in the field list query . I have tried to substitute the space “myfield\ name_solr” which gives me empty resukys without any error . I’m suing solr 7.x

Comment: Having spaces in your field name will create issues in many places outside of the `fl` parameter - I strongly advice you to reconsider using spaces and instead replace them with `_` or a different character when indexing and querying. But see [field listing in solr with “fl” parameter for a field having space in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575009/field-listing-in-solr-with-fl-parameter-for-a-field-having-space-in-between) for possible solutions .. but you really want to avoid this instead of trying to work around it over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces in field names are bad. You should not be creating those manually.

However, It seems that this field name is coming from the internal system during indexing and is creating automatically. In which case, you should substitute the space in the actual field name during indexing, using Update Request Processor and [FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.html), which can substitute spaces with dashes.

In fact, if you use schemaless mode, it should have happened already. I am unsure how exactly this field name got created, but the solution is still the same as above.

Comment: Agreed that spaces are bad it is presently a requirement for us . We are using managed schema and dynamic fields which is creating the fields with spaces . I’m able to query and filter but only the field list(fl) is causing an issue where I’m not able to use fl for the fields with spaces . I use the escape character ‘\’ and I do not see an error but can see empty results

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`"\ "`** (backslash followed by a space) like `attribute_Brand\ Name:Abc`in the query string or the filtered query field.